# How do you change the application focus in VBA macros when working with multiple MS applications

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am running a macro in Excel that creates and populates Word documents with values from a spreadsheet table. (A new file is created for each line.) If the Word file already exists, a MsgBox is displayed asking users if they want to save it to another name. (If Yes, a (Word) File Dialog is displayed.)

The problem is that if the user decides to save the file, the focus shifts to Word, and the next MsgBox prompt from Excel is hidden behind the Word application. So unless users manually switch back to Excel, they wouldn't see the MsgBox waiting for their input, and would probably think the application has stopped working. I've tried activating the Excel workbook before displaying the MsgBox, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I've also tried checking the ActiveWindow and Windows properties, but they indicate the workbook is the active (and only) window. How can I do the programmatic equivalent of clicking on the Excel workbook taking the focus away from Word?

Comment: Is Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp what you are looking for?

Comment: `AppActivate Application.Caption` run in Excel should bring Excel to the front.

Comment: You  already have one option mentioned above. May I see your code? I believe (and i could be wrong) there could be another way to solve the problem without having to specifically shift the focus back via code...

Comment: Thank you both for responding. AppActivate Application.Caption did the trick, thank you.  

I had checked Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp when I was searching the docs, but that method didn't exist for a Word app, and the Excel version had a constant for every MS app except Excel, so I couldn't use it to activate Excel.  But it looks like it should work for everything else.

Comment: Ooops.  I didn't see Siddharth's comment.  There's too much code to show here, but these were the lines I tried: 
```Application.Windows(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Activate      ' doesn't work
    ActiveWorkbook.Activate                                ' doesn't work
    ActiveSheet.Activate                                      'doesn't work ```

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered by Tim Williams:
"AppActivate Application.Caption run in Excel should bring Excel to the front. – Tim Williams"